# Overwriting the node has been created/updated drupal set messages

Tags: drupal

drupal 7 working fine tested.

```
/**

 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().

 */

function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'form_id':
      $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MY_MODULE_custom_submit';
    break;
  }

}

function MY_MODULE_custom_submit($form, &$form_state)

{

  //Get current messages and clear them.

  $messages = drupal_get_messages('status');

  drupal_set_message(t('Your custom status message here!'));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just need to get the right `form_id` in there. So if the node type is `article`, use `article_node_form`.

Also, don't forget to clear the caches at `admin/config/development/performance` so the system sees the changes.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */

function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    // Replace NODETYPE with the machine-readable name of the node type.
    case 'NODETYPE_node_form':
      $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MY_MODULE_custom_submit';
    break;
  }
}

function MY_MODULE_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //Get current messages and clear them.
  $messages = drupal_get_messages('status');
  drupal_set_message(t('Your custom status message here!'));
}
```

Hope that helps... :)